# In Work Calculator

Tags: java, netbeans, jtextfield, multiplication

I'm trying to do a calculator which just i need a multiplication . I will gave a example. Imagine 2 jTextField. I need to get data which is wrote to these jtextfields, and multiplicate them. And show result and jTextField3. This work needs the work under Action Performend jButton. It can be easy for you guys but i didnt understand. Thanks for reading..

```
num1=Integer.parseInt(txtfield1.getText());
num2=Integer.parseInt(txtfield2.getText());
total=num1*num2;
totalField.setText(String.valueOf(total));
```

Note:I tried this code but it didnt work. But i need just like that.

I just need a new code entire code about what did i said on the question . Ok i'm nut giving order to you but , just please help me. Or what should i do ?

Comment: How didn't it work? What was the outcome?

Comment: "it didn't work" ... come on, put some effort in.

Comment: I suggest checking the variables one by one to see where the problem is because the code is not a complicated one.

Comment: What's the question?  What particular problem are you facing?

Comment: Put some effort huh ? I'm trying to do/search about this for 3-4 hours. How can i put more effor ? Or instead of giving advice to me , why did not you put some effort and show me how to fix this problem ? I said i found this code on the net and it didnt work too. I didnt write this myself..

Comment: @Lyetnel: No one is questioning your effort to solve your problem, but we are asking for more effort in formulating your question so that we can easily understand it and be able to help. The general rule of thumb is that you should *put as much effort into **asking** your question as you'd like someone to put in **answering** it*. Since we're volunteers, that is certainly not asking too much of you. The best code you could post would be an [sscce](http://sscce.org), a small compilable and runnable program that demonstrates your problem and has no code unrelated to the problem present.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks effort and good-faith attempts to get clarification and effort of the OP have failed so far.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: I know , i'm sorry about that. Which i said in my comment, when i cant get any result of my codes about working/searching hours; then i'm asking to here. But he was just answer like a who is just trying to suppress his/her egos with blaming me . Thanks for your comment..

Comment: @Lyetnel I am not trying to use my ego to blame you. I'm requesting more information as I cannot reasonably answer it as I just don't know enough about the problem, as you didn't tell me. If you could be specific about the issue, including exception types, and behavior, or make it a self-contained piece of code that compiles and shows the issue, that would be good.

Comment: Don't thank me -- create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @hexafraction: I did it :) Please try to look your answer's comments :) Beside that, thanks for trying to help me...

Comment: @Lyetnel Please accept an answer to this question if it helped, using the tickmark to the left of it. It will turn green once you accept the answer.

Comment: @Lyetnel i stand by my criticism. nothing egotistical about it. the very least you could do is explain the error you are getting. 9 times out of 10 that will clearly describe what you are doing wrong.

Comment: @pstanton i did it long long time ago man :) Look we just have 1 answer all over the question. And i said my problem which i saw from my netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

2 problems with the code that we can see:

- NumberFormatException isn't caught
- Ints are not declared

Use this instead:

```
try{
    int num1=Integer.parseInt(txtfield1.getText());
    int num2=Integer.parseInt(txtfield2.getText());
    int total=num1*num2;
    totalField.setText(Integer.toString(total));
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    totalField.setText("Error in input");
}
```

Comment: This is not the question, the user wants to understand how he/she can execute this code as part of some action, such as actionEvent.

Comment: I don't see how `String.valueOf(int)` is the wrong method for `int->String` conversion, given the fact that it simply calls `Integer.toString` any way...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Oh, I was assuming it was int->char value for some reason.

Comment: I tried it too. It didnt work.

Comment: @Lyetnel What have you done to diagnose it other than asking here? What exception is thrown? Did it not work as the computer was turned off? Because there was no stack space? No bacon? Because the oniononization was too high for the JVM to start?

Comment: I just tried that code which in question . And i asked , how can i improve it or change it with which can be work...

Comment: @Lyetnel Again, in *which way* did it not work? You're not answering my inquiry which I need to help you.

Comment: I set the textfield's variable name's as mines. And it's giving error at "num1", "num2" "total=num1*num2;" " totalField" . And all of them has same problem. can't find symbol

Comment: @Lyetnel: again, there is critical information you're not telling us. If you get or see an error, then *post the complete error message* as part of your question. It usually tells you *exactly* what's wrong.

Comment: @Lyetnel Thanks, that seems sufficient. Try the edits. Now that we had the error message, it was enough for me to at least make an informed guess.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I think it's sufficient now.

Comment: @hexafraction Thanks now num1's error gone but , get still error about  totalfield as cannot field symbol. So, what should i use for showing num1*num2=total result to a jtextfield ? I think totalfield does not work

Comment: @Lyetnel I don't have enough info to answer that, but make sure totalfield is declared the same way as txtfield1 is.

Comment: @hexafraction yeah it's declared , or i think. I dont know. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Lyetnel No problem. IF you could tickmark this answer to accept it that would be good. If you still need help just post the relevant code(or if you're really lost, post all of it on [a pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and give us the link to the paste). We can then help you.

Comment: I did. Thanks dude but , i need a already code which can show the result to jtextfield which already calculated from here...                 int num1=Integer.parseInt(jTextField4.getText());
    int num2=Integer.parseInt(jTextField5.getText());
    int total=num1*num2;

Comment: @Lyetnel Again, this is like doing surgery with the doctor's eyes closed. We need to see what is around as well. It's unfortunately late in my timezone but I'll help how I can once I see enough for me to understand what your code is doing. Thanks!

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/yFIa3j5.png ^^. I get it . Try to look at this picture then

Comment: @Lyetnel I don't think I can solve it with the picture as I need to see how that field was declared in code.

Comment: I tried this code instead of yours and i get "method setText in class JTextComponent cannot be applied to given types; Required:String , found int , reason:actual argument int cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion

Comment: Codes are , try{
    int num1=Integer.parseInt(jTextField4.getText());
    int num2=Integer.parseInt(jTextField5.getText());
    int result=num1*num2;
    jTextField6.setText(result);
    
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    
}

Comment: @Lyetnel Oh, you need `jTextfield6.setText(Integer.toString(result));` for the last line. Keep the bracket after it as well.